# Using the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be an abelian group of order $k$. If $l$ divides $k$, prove that $H$ has a subgroup of order $l$. Noting that I am wanting to use the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.

Attempt:

$k = p_{1}^{a_{1}}$ $p_{2}^{a_{2}}$ $...$ $p_{m}^{a_{m}}$

$l = p_{1}^{b_{1}}$ $p_{2}^{b_{2}}$ $...$ $p_{n}^{a_{n}}$

$b_{i} \leq a_{i}$

So then we have something like $(\mathbb{Z}_{p_{1}^{t_{11}}} \times$ $...$ $\times \mathbb{Z}_{p_{1}^{t_{k1}}})$$\times (\mathbb{Z}_{p_{1}^{t_{12}}} \times$ $...$ $\times \mathbb{Z}_{p_{1}^{t_{k2}}})$$\times ...$

Now from here I am not sure what to do to finish the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Cyclic groups of order $k$ have subgroups of order $l$ for all $l$ dividing $k$.  Use the fundamental theorem with this fact to prove the desired result.

More specifically, using your notation, notice that for all $j$ we have,

$$\sum_i t_{ij}=a_j$$

and for all $\mathbb{Z}_{p_j^{t_{ij}}}$ we have subgroups of order $p_j^{c}$ for all $1\le c\le t_{ij}$.  See if you can find a way to choose subgroups of order $p_j^{c_{ij}}$ so that for all $j$ we have

$$\sum_ic_{ij}=b_j$$

Comment: Hmm would I take a subgroup generated by $g^{p^{a-b}}$?